# Save excel file from main directory to database model in Django

Tags: python, django

How to save the file generated from pd.dataframe to certain database record.

This is the view..

```
@csrf_exempt
def Data_Communication(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_sets_number = (len(request.POST)) - 1
        Data_Sets_asNestedList = []
        Data_set_id = request.POST.get('id')
        Data_instance = Data_Sets.objects.get(pk=Data_set_id)
        for x in range(data_sets_number):
            i = 1
            Data_Sets_asNestedList.append(request.POST.getlist('Data'+str(i)))
            i = i + 1
        pd.DataFrame(Data_Sets_asNestedList).to_excel('output.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
        print(Data_Sets_asNestedList)
        return HttpResponse('1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to associate the generated Excel file with the model `Data_Sets`, then you'd probably want to add a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield) to that model:

```py
class Data_Sets(models.Model):
    excel_file = fields.FileField()
```

Once you've created the Excel file in your view, you can then associate it with the new field:

```py
from django.core.files import File

@csrf_exempt
def Data_Communication(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_sets_number = (len(request.POST)) - 1
        Data_Sets_asNestedList = []
        Data_set_id = request.POST.get('id')
        Data_instance = Data_Sets.objects.get(pk=Data_set_id)
        for x in range(data_sets_number):
            i = 1
            Data_Sets_asNestedList.append(request.POST.getlist('Data'+str(i)))
            i = i + 1
        pd.DataFrame(Data_Sets_asNestedList).to_excel('output.xlsx', header=False, index=False)

        # Associate the Excel file with the model
        with open('output.xlsx', 'rb') as excel:
            Data_instance.excel_file.save('output.xlsx', File(excel))

        print(Data_Sets_asNestedList)
        return HttpResponse('1')
```

The excel file itself will be saved into the folder specified by the [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-root) setting in your `settings.py`, and the model will point to that file via the `excel_file` attribute.

Note that you may want to generate a unique filename for `output.xlsx` to avoid  requests from treading on each other.

Additional info on saving a file can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save).

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't randomly insert your data to database, use django validation system to validate your data first.
2. check bulk_create api to store large chunks of records.

Comment: This data is not from user form, it is sent using python client using post request (sensor data). Also, I want to save the data and store it in the server and only the url of the file is on the database. Will it work ?